# Why is RDP not working anymore?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

My computer (Win7 x64 Ultimate) is behind an ADSL router.  I have previously set up NAT on the router to direct RDP calls to my computer.  I have also given my computer a static IP address on the network so that routing doesn't fall out of date.  Externally, I have a dynamic DNS from dyndns.org.  This has been serving me perfectly well... until the last couple of weeks.  I don't know what happened, but suddenly I cannot connect to RDP from a remote computer any more.  I don't remember changing any critical settings.  Windows firewall has allowed port 3389.

So what else can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha!  Found the culprit!  My ESET antivirus/firewall was blocking it.  Silly me, that should have been my first suspicion... [blushes]...

Comment: You didn't mention a software firewall in your original question, but +1 for your answer anyway because it describes the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your router is forwarding inbound traffic from TCP port 3389 to your computer internally that has the static IP address and is hosting the RDP service on that same port number.

Additionally, use a different TCP port number on the outside if your router will support that.  This is "security by obscurity," so don't take it as a *really great* security measure, but it will cut out at least some of the script kiddies and those who don't scan ports to find various services in their dark hacking activities.